# XAML [Control] is not supported in a Windows App Project

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

When opening a XAML page or usercontrol in Visual Studio in my project, the IDE will tell me that the [Control] is not supported, for all controls. It will also not show me the design view for the XAML.

I've disabled all Visual Studio plugins, and the only thing that has worked consistently is pulling the entire project from source control and reopening the project from scratch. After closing Visual Studio the problem happens again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one took me a long time to figure out. Because I am using SQLite for this project, I could no longer use the "Any CPU" configuration for this project (near the debug/release dropdown). I setup a new configuration so the phone version would use ARM, and the desktop version would use x86. This is when I started to see the problem.

To fix the issue, try toggling between the different configurations. Toggling between "My custom configuration -> x64 -> My custom configuration", usually clears it up for me, but try switching a couple more times to different architectures if this doesn't work.

You only need to do this one time when you open the project, and all of your views will work correctly from then on (Intellisense, and the Design View specifically). I'll update the question to include Visual Studio 2015 if I run into the problem there.

Comment: After changing the configuration hit the "Save All" button and restart VS, this will solve the problem.